# How to display list of files and subfolders in datagridview using VB

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know how to display list of files and subfolders in datagridview in Form1 using VB net. I need a simple code which can show me the list of files within "C:\VB SAVE" directory to DataGridView1. I have below code by I'm not sure how to make it show files in "C:\VB SAVE". Which part of the code I should change ?Please help me
Thanks

```
Imports System.IO
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim arrList As New ArrayList
    Form1_Load(StartPath & "Files", arrList)
    Dim filesInfo = From file As IO.FileInfo In arrList _
                       Select file.Name, file.Length, file.LastWriteTime, file.CreationTime
    DataGridView1.DataSource = filesInfo.ToList
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is very broad. Try a little code, search the internet if you need to, then if you have any problems, ask here. People will be more than happy to help if you show you have made some attempt to do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, i  have edited my question by including some code as you suggested. Hope there is some answer to my question.

Comment: In your `Form1_Load` you have `Form1_Load(StartPath & "Files", arrList)`? Is that correct or a typo?

Comment: Why are you calling Form1_Load from Form1_Load? Looks like a endless loop. What is arrList doing? You are sending an empty ArrayList as Event Args to your recursive Form1_Load. For new code List(Of T) is recommended.

Comment: `From file As IO.FileInfo In arrList` There is nothing in arrList so how can you select from it?

Comment: So, how should i write the arrList ? Actually not Form1 but  getCompleteFileList1(StartPath & "Files", arrList)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using TreeView inside Datagridview?

[TreeView Inside Datagridview](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=treeview%20in%20datagridview%20vb.net&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDm9Lwz5TeAhUBxrwKHaKzAoEQ_AUICSgA&biw=1536&bih=783&dpr=1.25)

Comment: I prefer not to use TreeView in a mean time....i want to use Datagridview directly.